# Symfony/PHP DateTimeZone missing timezones

Tags: php, symfony

I've got a Symfony API that is storing the users timezone as part of the login process. However, it seems certain timezones causes an error. Using `'America/Buenos_Aires'` as an example value being sent, the following code causes 500 error to be thrown.

```
$validator->validate($request->request, new Assert\Collection([
        'username' => new AppAssert\Chain([
            new Assert\Type('string'),
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
        ]),
        'password' => new AppAssert\Chain([
            new Assert\Type('string'),
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
        ]),
        'timezone' => new AppAssert\Chain([
            new Assert\Type('string'),
            new Assert\NotIdenticalTo(''),
            new Assert\Choice([
                'choices' => \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(),
                'strict' => true,
            ]),
        ]),
    ]));
```

Looking at this post https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70816 it states to use `DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC`, which I've tried

`'choices' => \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC),`

but still to no avial.

The client is using Moment JS which seems to sometimes return `America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires` and sometimes `America/Buenos_Aires` but 
 `America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires` works fine.

Comment: It seems to be `America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires`

Comment: Moment JS seems to return both. Sometimes `America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires` and `America/Buenos_Aires`, the latter erroring.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, I was missing `\` off `DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC`

Full correct code

```
 'timezone' => new AppAssert\Chain([
            new Assert\Type('string'),
            new Assert\NotIdenticalTo(''),
            new Assert\Choice([
                'choices' => \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(\DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC),
                'strict' => true,
            ]),
        ]),
```